# Neo4j Cypher: Get mutual friends network

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, gremlin

I believe what I have should be a very straightforward, yet for some reason I am not getting forward. I have the classical social network setup where users can be friends with each other. I know want to visualize an user's network with D3.js

For that, its obvious how to get the friends

```
user -[:friend]- friend
```

Now, I also want to display the connections among the user's friends, so that it nicely clusters in a force-directed graph. This is however my current problem, as I'd like to find out how the "friend" set is connected with each other. I first thought

```
with friend
match friend -[connection:friend]- friend
```

would work, but obviously doesn't. I seem to overlook one very obvious thing, but I'm not sure what.

EDIT: Gremlin is welcome too, could be more performant if its more traversal-y/explicit

Comment: dont do the latter statement after the MATCH at `with friend ...` but rather put it directly into the MATCH phase like `MATCH user-[:friend]-firend-[connection:friend]-friend2 `. does this work for you?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know thats how i can get friend-of-friends, but that is a superset of what I want. I only want the friends of friends that are also friends with the user, and that is also optional. if you assume everyone has 100 friends, i want the user, his 100 friends and how those 101 people are friends with each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will inspire you to a solution using Gremlin.  I adapted your problem to the standard TinkerPop toy graph.  I set out to figure out the following:

For a particular vertex, find all the vertices it is connected to and then how each of those vertices in that total set are related to one another.  That sounds like what you are looking for given your description.

So I started with:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()              
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.v(1).outE.as('x').inV.loop(2){it.loops<3}{true}.select
==>[x:e[7][1-knows->2]]
==>[x:e[8][1-knows->4]]
==>[x:e[9][1-created->3]]
==>[x:e[10][4-created->5]]
==>[x:e[11][4-created->3]]
```

For vertex with id 1, get all the out edges then loop that again to get the friends edges, and finally select out the values of the "x" step.  That gets you to at least knowing what that subgraph is around g.v(1), but as I read your question you wanted to go a step further to restrict the subgraph to just those vertices that are connected to g.v(1). Looking at the results, e[10] really shouldn't be included because there is no edge between g.v(1) and g.v(5).

I further refined the query to eliminate that relationship from the subgraph:

```
gremlin> x=[g.v(1)];g.v(1).out.aggregate(x).back(2).outE.filter{x.contains(it.inV.next())}.as('e').inV.loop(3){it.loops<3}{true}.select 
==>[e:e[7][1-knows->2]]
==>[e:e[8][1-knows->4]]
==>[e:e[9][1-created->3]]
==>[e:e[11][4-created->3]]
```

So the above basically says,

- initialize an list x that will hold all the vertices that should be held in the subgraph.
- g.v(1).out.aggregate(x) basically puts all the vertices in "x" that I want in the subgraph in addition to the one I initialized it with
- back track to the start of the the traversal and find outEdges that contain vertices in x then loop it as before and select out the value of the "e" step which is the edge list.

Now you can see that e[10] is no longer in the results.  From here you can construct output for visualization pretty easily.